# Why does nsepy get_history return an empty dataframe for stocks?

Tags: python, nsepy

Running this with nsepy 0.4 and Python 2.7 returns an empty dataframe. This was working until last week.

```
from nsepy import get_history as gh
from datetime import date

stk1 = gh(symbol='SBIN',start=date(2015,1,1),end=date(2015,1,10))
print(stk1)
```

**Output:**

```
Empty DataFrame

Columns: [Symbol, Series, Prev Close, Open, High, Low, Last, Close, VWAP, Volume, Turnover, Trades, Deliverable Volume, %Deliverble]

Index: []
```

---

Whereas, this works:

```
stk1 = gh(symbol='NIFTY',start=date(2015,1,1),end=date(2015,1,10), index=True)
print(stk1)
```

**Output:**

```
Date        Open     High      Low    Close     Volume      Turnover

2015-01-01  8272.80  8294.70  8248.75  8284.00   56560411  2.321880e+10

2015-01-02  8288.70  8410.60  8288.70  8395.45  101887024  4.715720e+10

2015-01-05  8407.95  8445.60  8363.90  8378.40  118160545  5.525520e+10

2015-01-06  8325.30  8327.85  8111.35  8127.35  172799618  8.089190e+10

2015-01-07  8118.65  8151.20  8065.45  8102.10  164075424  7.464330e+10

2015-01-08  8191.40  8243.50  8167.30  8234.60  143802802  8.147400e+10

2015-01-09  8285.45  8303.30  8190.80  8284.50  152612528  9.305950e+10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

NSE's website has been updated making nsepy 0.4 incompatible, hence it will not work now. please uninstall nsepy and and run `pip install nsepy` again to install version 0.5 which has fix for this.

Comment: Hi I am using nsepy==0.7, still not worked ? any idea ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not working for me as well, but futures data is working.

I think NSE has done some update on their server.

I am using nsepy package version 0.7 as checked by the following code

```
import nsepy
print(nsepy.__VERSION__)
```

Comment: If you did not find an answer from this post, please ask a new question. Provide enough details to not be marked as a duplicate and also reference this post, be sure to explain how your problem is different.